Csharp Swig files with SwigType
I have a CPP project and trying to create CSharp API using Swig.
Created a interface.i file to wrap all the header files.  Compiling the file generates .cs files and few files with pattern SWIGTYPE_p_.....
What is the use of these files SWIGTYPE_p_....   Can I delete these files and only include .cs files in the build ?
Observed that few SWIGTYPE_p... files are not getting generated where previously they were generated. I have not made any code changes recently and have no idea where to look at.
Below is my sample .i file
// Swig interface file for C# wrapeer for c++ dll
//export module CPP_interface;

% module cppwrappername
% include <std_common.i>
% include <typemaps.i>
% include <std_string.i>
% include <std_wstring.i>
% include <std_vector.i>
% include <std_map.i>
% include <std_pair.i>
% include <windows.i>

using namespace std;

#define unix

% apply char[] { const unsigned char*};

namespace std {
    % apply const string& { string& };
};


#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
% apply sem_t* { Semaphore };

% {
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <locale>


#include <emperror.h>
#include <empmessage.h>


%}

% ignore  operator<<;
% ignore  operator=;
% ignore  operator==;
//%include "windows.h"

% include "emperror.h"
% include "empmessage.h"

SWIGTYPE_p_emperror.cs file NOT generated. Any pointers where to look at ? I am new to SWIG

These files are used to convert the wrapped classes of c++ into partial classes of c#.
Refer eg. to:
https://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CSharp.html
20.8.6 Turning wrapped classes into partial classes
Also other Type-Conversions are made by putting them into these wrapper-classes, like arrays or int's.
"The default wrapping treats arrays as pointers and as such simple type wrapper classes are generated, eg SWIGTYPE_p_int when wrapping the C type int [] or int *. This gives a rather restricted use of the underlying unmanaged code and the most practical way to use arrays is to enhance or customise with one of the following three approaches; namely the SWIG C arrays library, P/Invoke default array marshalling or pinned arrays."

yes, thats the concern. Few of the files are not getting generated. Eg SWIGTYPE_p_long.cs.   Swigtype_p_time._tcs, Swigtype_p_short.cs, SwigType_p_MTInt4.cs.   Not sure where to look at to find the root cause of the issue
